# PHP session variables are not passing to next page

Tags: php, session-variables

I am using this code to retrieve php session variables.

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username1'];
$password = $_SESSION['password1'];
echo $username;
```

When I execute it, I get the following error.

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie – headers already sent by (output started at /home/practice/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php:13) in /home/practice/public_html/wp-content/plugins/php-execution-plugin/includes/class.php_execution.php(273) : eval()’d code on line 2

If I remove `session_start()`, I get no error.

But in both cases, the session variable is not retrieved and the command `echo $username;`
doesn't show anything.

Comment: Is `display_errors` on? else `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` You might see what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message already tells you, that you've ouput something before the session_start call:

```
output started at /home/practice/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php:13
```

The output is in the header.php file in line 13.

You have to start the session before any output to the client is sent.

Comment: thank you. solved the problem. i put the session start () at the top of the header.php.

Answer (score 1):

You have something being output on the page before the `session_start();`. Make sure that the `session_start();` comes before any `echo`/`print` statements, or HTML.

Your script is outputting something at line 13 in `header.php`. Put `session_start();` before that, if not on the first line of the script.

When you remove `session_start();` the session retrieval isn't attempted and the problem (that caused the error) goes away. PHP doesn't care that the variables you're trying to output don't exist. That's just how PHP is (though it will generate a `Notice`).

Comment: if i remove the session_start() and put it at the top, the error removes but i still dont get the session variables.

Comment: @umerkhayam I explain why in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use sessions inside a wordpress installation. The code is too dirty to rely on the  "no output".

Can't you use users table in wordpress as credential and authentication method?